# how to display 3 arraylist's in a jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist, foreach

i have to display 3 array lists in a table.. the arraylists are forwarded from a servlet. the value s coming to the jsp. as if we display one array list alone the prg is woking but to display 3 array lists is a problem.

```
<c:forEach var="auctionDO" items="${auctionDOListServlet}">
<tr div class="odd"> 
    <td style="font-size:14px;"><a href="/myproject/s/PermanentUserAuctionHistoryInner"><c:out value="${auctionDO.auctionName}"/> </a></td>
    <td><c:out value="${auctionDO.endDate}"/>   </td>
    <td><c:out value="${auctionDO.status}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${depotDo.depotName}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${userAuctionRelDo.bidAmt}"/></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

as auctionDOListServlet is provided in foreach its displaying correctly.. the depotDO and userAuctionRelDO is not being displayed..

how do i display the other 2 arraylists??

the arraylists are passed from servlet as follows

```
request.setAttribute("auctionDOListServlet", auctionDOListServlet);
request.setAttribute("depotDOListServlet", depotDOListServlet);
request.setAttribute("userAuctionRelDOListServlet", userAuctionRelDOListServlet);
```

i have combined the three list into 1 list

```
megaList.addAll(auctionDOListServlet);
megaList.addAll(depotDOListServlet);
megaList.addAll(userAuctionRelDOListServlet);
```

now how do i display this in for each?? would this work?
where mega is the name of the variable??

```
   <td><c:out value="${mega.endDate}"/> </td>
```

this now hows errors for depot name and bidamt as they are in a totally different DO.. wat to do??

Comment: Well, you have given auctionDO in the variable and why are you trying to get depotDo.depotName and userAuctionRelDo.bidAmt... It is simply illogical.

Answer (score 2):

> how do i display the other 2 arraylists??

As you did.  `depotDOListServlet` and `userAuctionRelDOListServlet`  are two array lists then same way you can use `<c:forEach></c:forEach>` to iterate those lists.

```
<c:forEach var="auctionDO" items="${auctionDOListServlet}">
 <tr div class="odd"> 
  <td style="font-size:14px;"><a href="/myproject/s/PermanentUserAuctionHistoryInner"><c:out value="${auctionDO.auctionName}"/> </a></td>
  <td><c:out value="${auctionDO.endDate}"/>   </td>
  <td><c:out value="${auctionDO.status}"/></td>
  <c:forEach var="depotDo" items="${depotDOListServlet}">
   <td><c:out value="${depotDo.depotName}"/></td>
  </c:forEach>
  <c:forEach var="userAuctionRelDo" items="${userAuctionRelDOListServlet}">
   <td><c:out value="${userAuctionRelDo.bidAmt}"/></td>
  </c:forEach>
 </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

**Remember** that for every item in list `auctionDOListServlet` rest two lists will iterate each time.

Comment: Aniket.. i implemented your code.. but the problem is that there were only 2 rows too  be displayed but now four rows are being displayed and now actually rows and columns have got messed up.. name and duration columns are empty. status column is displaying name, bid amt is displayed is status and 3 extra columns have sprung up with one column being empty and the other 2 having bid amounts, that should have been in 2 separate rows..

Comment: @user3060890 : Yes, that's what I told you in last line of my answer. I don't know exact list contents but you can create one list combining all three and just display.

Comment: Aniket.. how do i combine 3 lists, that are based on 3 different data objects??

Comment: @user3060890 : create another class with members as 3 array list or members as fields that you want to display on JSP. And create array list of newly created class and just pass to JSP. You are done.

Comment: aniket thanks.. but another question.. i have edited the question field.. how do u display a mega list?? i am not getting the page itself...

Comment: @user3060890 : No this(`${mega.AuctionDO.endDate}`) will not work, because addAll method just add all elements not the `AuctionDO`. I don't know the type of list. Is it of some class?

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over one particular array. This has no effect on other arrays. The other arrays are not being iterated over.

I would create a container object that holds these three entities together, and then put these in a list.

Or you could for a for loop and call getValueAt(anIntValue) on the list. This way you could get the correct value for every list.

Comment: hi Oliver.. could you pls give an example for that for loop in context with my jsp code?