# how to code foreach involving 3 lists in jstl?

Tags: java, list, jsp, for-loop, jstl

this is a follow on from this question..
[how to display 3 arraylist's in a jsp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084755/how-to-display-3-arraylists-in-a-jsp)

well i have this following code in java.. i need an equivalent one for use in jsp.. jstl codes preferred..

```
 int i=0;
 for(AuctionDo list : auctionDOList)                                   
    {
     System.out.println(" "+ list.getAuctionId()+ " " + depotDolist.get(i).getDepotName() + " " + userAuctionRelDolist2.get(i).getAuctionId() );
     i++;
    }
```

the three lists are received in jsp.. thankyou.. 
1 very important thing i want to display the lists in one row in a table.. so multiple foreach is out of option and tried merging the lists.. pretty much didnt work..

Answer (score 1):

You have to do like this

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="firstListElement" varStatus="counter"> 
  <%-- auction id of list --%>
  ${list.auctionId}
  <%-- depot name of depotList item based on iteration count --%>
  ${depotList[counter.count].depotName} 
   <%-- auctionId of userAuctionRelDolist2 item based on iteration count --%>
  ${userAuctionRelDolist2[counter.count].auctionId}
</c:forEach>
```

counter keeps tracking of the iteration count variable.

Note: Since the `forEach` loop depends on the size of the first list. This will not work correctly when the size of the `depotList` or `userAuctionrelDolist` is greater than the size of the first list

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
<c:forEach items="${auctionDOList}" var="list" varStatus="counter">
    ${list.auctionId} ${depotList[counter.count].depotName} ${userAuctionRelDolist2[counter.count].auctionId}
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need forEach to do this. Refer this links

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm

http://www.crazysquirrel.com/computing/java/jsp/jstl-forEach.jspx

being more specific you'll need nested forEach

http://www.coderanch.com/t/288775/JSP/java/jstl-nested-foreach

http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/simple-jsp-example/NestedForEach.shtml