# displaying multiple lists in a single row/table using foreach

Tags: java, list, foreach, jstl

i am new to jstl.. i am trying to display 4 lists in 1 row in a table.. 
i followed this "
[how to code foreach involving 3 lists in jstl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190153/how-to-code-foreach-involving-3-lists-in-jstl) "

```
 <c:forEach items="${actionList}" var="action" varStatus="counter"> 
 <tr>
 <td><c:out value= "${action.cut}"/></td>
 <td><c:out value= "${dustList[counter.count].dust}"/></td>
 <td><c:out value= "${myList[counter.count].name}"/></td>
 <td><c:out value= "${megaList[counter.count].megaprice}"/></td>
 </tr>
```

well the result was i got the  first column alrt.. but the rest of the columns aint showing anything.. the servlet gets the values alrt..

```
 request.setAttribute("actionList", actionList);
 request.setAttribute("dustList", dustList);
 request.setAttribute("myList", myList);
 request.setAttribute("megaList", megaList);
```

the passing is also happening correctly.. the  calling is also correct.. so where am i going wrong? why is only one list being displayed?? console is displaying no error ..

Comment: Please show briefly your relevant java code.

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/users/2702504/octopus) chk out this q..

Comment: all lists are of size 4. varIndex?? am new to jstl?? could u giv an example??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to use is the `index` of the varStatus not the `count`

```
<td><c:out value= "${dustList[counter.index].dust}"/></td>
<td><c:out value= "${myList[counter.index].name}"/></td>
```

**Note**

${status.index} = 0 based index

${status.count} = 1 based index

I also assume that there are methods such as `getMegaprice()` or `megaprice` is public.

Comment: how did http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190153/how-to-code-foreach-involving-3-lists-in-jstl get the output???

Comment: Hmm, maybe it didn't.